# Text Editor com suporte a RTF

Tags: javascript, jquery, delphi

Preciso encontrar um editor de texto com suporte a RTF.

**Objetivo:** Escrever e formatar em html e salvar em RTF,  depois pegar em RTF e editar em html.

Pesquisei a documentação de vários editores para ver se existe algo do tipo e não encontrei.

Preciso em RTF por que a aplicação feita em *Delphi* utiliza um editor de texto  (`TRichEdit`) que salva apenas em RTF,
então minha aplicação web deve entender RTF e poder salvar para que a leitura nas duas aplicações sejam feitas corretamente.

Alguém teve o mesmo problema?

Quais são as possíveis soluções para isto ?

Comment: Não entendo o que bootstrap tem haver com o rtf ou o delphi, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Meu editor html utiliza bootstrap chamado summernote, ele infezlimente não possui suporte para conversão de rtftohtml htmltorft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ficar sem margem de problemas futuros, sugiro que implemente as duas plataformas (Web e Desktop) você pode converter todo RTF para HTML com o procedimento a seguir:

**Inclua em seu projeto:**

```
  /**
   * RTF parser/formatter
   *
   * This code reads RTF files and formats the RTF data to HTML.
   *
   * PHP version 5
   *
   * @author     Alexander van Oostenrijk
   * @copyright  2014 Alexander van Oostenrijk
   * @license    GNU
   * @version    1
   * @link       http://www.independent-software.com
   * 
   * Sample of use:
   * 
   * $reader = new RtfReader();
   * $rtf = file_get_contents("itc.rtf"); // or use a string
   * $reader->Parse($rtf);
   * //$reader->root->dump(); // to see what the reader read
   * $formatter = new RtfHtml();
   * echo $formatter->Format($reader->root);   
   */

  class RtfElement
  {
    protected function Indent($level)
    {
      for($i = 0; $i < $level * 2; $i++) echo "&nbsp;";
    }
  }

  class RtfGroup extends RtfElement
  {
    public $parent;
    public $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->parent = null;
      $this->children = array();
    }

    public function GetType()
    {
      // No children?
      if(sizeof($this->children) == 0) return null;
      // First child not a control word?
      $child = $this->children[0];
      if(get_class($child) != "RtfControlWord") return null;
      return $child->word;
    }    

    public function IsDestination()
    {
      // No children?
      if(sizeof($this->children) == 0) return null;
      // First child not a control symbol?
      $child = $this->children[0];
      if(get_class($child) != "RtfControlSymbol") return null;
      return $child->symbol == '*';
    }

    public function dump($level = 0)
    {
      echo "<div>";
      $this->Indent($level);
      echo "{";
      echo "</div>";

      foreach($this->children as $child)
      {
        if(get_class($child) == "RtfGroup")
        {
          if ($child->GetType() == "fonttbl") continue;
          if ($child->GetType() == "colortbl") continue;
          if ($child->GetType() == "stylesheet") continue;
          if ($child->GetType() == "info") continue;
          // Skip any pictures:
          if (substr($child->GetType(), 0, 4) == "pict") continue;
          if ($child->IsDestination()) continue;
        }
        $child->dump($level + 2);
      }

      echo "<div>";
      $this->Indent($level);
      echo "}";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  }

  class RtfControlWord extends RtfElement
  {
    public $word;
    public $parameter;

    public function dump($level)
    {
      echo "<div style='color:green'>";
      $this->Indent($level);
      echo "WORD {$this->word} ({$this->parameter})";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  }

  class RtfControlSymbol extends RtfElement
  {
    public $symbol;
    public $parameter = 0;

    public function dump($level)
    {
      echo "<div style='color:blue'>";
      $this->Indent($level);
      echo "SYMBOL {$this->symbol} ({$this->parameter})";
      echo "</div>";
    }    
  }

  class RtfText extends RtfElement
  {
    public $text;

    public function dump($level)
    {
      echo "<div style='color:red'>";
      $this->Indent($level);
      echo "TEXT {$this->text}";
      echo "</div>";
    }    
  }

  class RtfReader
  {
    public $root = null;

    protected function GetChar()
    {
      $this->char = $this->rtf[$this->pos++];
    }

    protected function ParseStartGroup()
    {
      // Store state of document on stack.
      $group = new RtfGroup();
      if($this->group != null) $group->parent = $this->group;
      if($this->root == null)
      {
        $this->group = $group;
        $this->root = $group;
      }
      else
      {
        array_push($this->group->children, $group);
        $this->group = $group;
      }
    }

    protected function is_letter()
    {
      if(ord($this->char) >= 65 && ord($this->char) <= 90) return TRUE;
      if(ord($this->char) >= 90 && ord($this->char) <= 122) return TRUE;
      return FALSE;
    }

    protected function is_digit()
    {
      if(ord($this->char) >= 48 && ord($this->char) <= 57) return TRUE;
      return FALSE;
    }

    protected function ParseEndGroup()
    {
      // Retrieve state of document from stack.
      $this->group = $this->group->parent;
    }

    protected function ParseControlWord()
    {
      $this->GetChar();
      $word = "";
      while($this->is_letter())
      {
        $word .= $this->char;
        $this->GetChar();
      }

      // Read parameter (if any) consisting of digits.
      // Paramater may be negative.
      $parameter = null;
      $negative = false;
      if($this->char == '-') 
      {
        $this->GetChar();
        $negative = true;
      }
      while($this->is_digit())
      {
        if($parameter == null) $parameter = 0;
        $parameter = $parameter * 10 + $this->char;
        $this->GetChar();
      }
      if($parameter === null) $parameter = 1;
      if($negative) $parameter = -$parameter;

      // If this is \u, then the parameter will be followed by 
      // a character.
      if($word == "u") 
      {
      }
      // If the current character is a space, then
      // it is a delimiter. It is consumed.
      // If it's not a space, then it's part of the next
      // item in the text, so put the character back.
      else
      {
        if($this->char != ' ') $this->pos--; 
      }

      $rtfword = new RtfControlWord();
      $rtfword->word = $word;
      $rtfword->parameter = $parameter;
      array_push($this->group->children, $rtfword);
    }

    protected function ParseControlSymbol()
    {
      // Read symbol (one character only).
      $this->GetChar();
      $symbol = $this->char;

      // Symbols ordinarily have no parameter. However, 
      // if this is \', then it is followed by a 2-digit hex-code:
      $parameter = 0;
      if($symbol == '\'')
      {
        $this->GetChar(); 
        $parameter = $this->char;
        $this->GetChar(); 
        $parameter = hexdec($parameter . $this->char);
      }

      $rtfsymbol = new RtfControlSymbol();
      $rtfsymbol->symbol = $symbol;
      $rtfsymbol->parameter = $parameter;
      array_push($this->group->children, $rtfsymbol);
    }

    protected function ParseControl()
    {
      // Beginning of an RTF control word or control symbol.
      // Look ahead by one character to see if it starts with
      // a letter (control world) or another symbol (control symbol):
      $this->GetChar();
      $this->pos--;
      if($this->is_letter()) 
        $this->ParseControlWord();
      else
        $this->ParseControlSymbol();
    }

    protected function ParseText()
    {
      // Parse plain text up to backslash or brace,
      // unless escaped.
      $text = "";

      do
      {
        $terminate = false;
        $escape = false;

        // Is this an escape?
        if($this->char == '\\')
        {
          // Perform lookahead to see if this
          // is really an escape sequence.
          $this->GetChar();
          switch($this->char)
          {
            case '\\': $text .= '\\'; break;
            case '{': $text .= '{'; break;
            case '}': $text .= '}'; break;
            default:
              // Not an escape. Roll back.
              $this->pos = $this->pos - 2;
              $terminate = true;
              break;
          }
        }
        else if($this->char == '{' || $this->char == '}')
        {
          $this->pos--;
          $terminate = true;
        }

        if(!$terminate && !$escape)
        {
          $text .= $this->char;
          $this->GetChar();
        }
      }
      while(!$terminate && $this->pos < $this->len);

      $rtftext = new RtfText();
      $rtftext->text = $text;
      array_push($this->group->children, $rtftext);
    }

    public function Parse($rtf)
    {
      $this->rtf = $rtf;
      $this->pos = 0;
      $this->len = strlen($this->rtf);
      $this->group = null;
      $this->root = null;

      while($this->pos < $this->len)
      {
        // Read next character:
        $this->GetChar();

        // Ignore \r and \n
        if($this->char == "\n" || $this->char == "\r") continue;

        // What type of character is this?
        switch($this->char)
        {
          case '{':
            $this->ParseStartGroup();
            break;
          case '}':
            $this->ParseEndGroup();
            break;
          case '\\':
            $this->ParseControl();
            break;
          default:
            $this->ParseText();
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  class RtfState
  {
    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->Reset();
    }

    public function Reset()
    {
      $this->bold = false;
      $this->italic = false;
      $this->underline = false;
      $this->end_underline = false;
      $this->strike = false;
      $this->hidden = false;
      $this->fontsize = 0;
    }
  }

  class RtfHtml
  {
    public function Format($root)
    {
      $this->output = "";
      // Create a stack of states:
      $this->states = array();
      // Put an initial standard state onto the stack:
      $this->state = new RtfState();
      array_push($this->states, $this->state);
      $this->FormatGroup($root);
      return $this->output;
    }

    protected function FormatGroup($group)
    {
      // Can we ignore this group?
      if ($group->GetType() == "fonttbl") return;
      if ($group->GetType() == "colortbl") return;
      if ($group->GetType() == "stylesheet") return;
      if ($group->GetType() == "info") return;
      // Skip any pictures:
      if (substr($group->GetType(), 0, 4) == "pict") return;
      if ($group->IsDestination()) return;

      // Push a new state onto the stack:
      $this->state = clone $this->state;
      array_push($this->states, $this->state);

      foreach($group->children as $child)
      {
        if(get_class($child) == "RtfGroup") $this->FormatGroup($child);
        if(get_class($child) == "RtfControlWord") $this->FormatControlWord($child);
        if(get_class($child) == "RtfControlSymbol") $this->FormatControlSymbol($child);
        if(get_class($child) == "RtfText") $this->FormatText($child);
      }

      // Pop state from stack.
      array_pop($this->states);
      $this->state = $this->states[sizeof($this->states)-1];
    }

    protected function FormatControlWord($word)
    {
      if($word->word == "plain") $this->state->Reset();
      if($word->word == "b") $this->state->bold = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "i") $this->state->italic = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "ul") $this->state->underline = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "ulnone") $this->state->end_underline = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "strike") $this->state->strike = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "v") $this->state->hidden = $word->parameter;
      if($word->word == "fs") $this->state->fontsize = ceil(($word->parameter / 24) * 16);

      if($word->word == "par") $this->output .= "<p>";

      // Characters:
      if($word->word == "lquote") $this->output .= "&lsquo;";
      if($word->word == "rquote") $this->output .= "&rsquo;";
      if($word->word == "ldblquote") $this->output .= "&ldquo;";
      if($word->word == "rdblquote") $this->output .= "&rdquo;";
      if($word->word == "emdash") $this->output .= "&mdash;";
      if($word->word == "endash") $this->output .= "&ndash;";
      if($word->word == "bullet") $this->output .= "&bull;";
      if($word->word == "u") $this->output .= "&loz;";
    }

    protected function BeginState()
    {
      $span = "";
      if($this->state->bold) $span .= "font-weight:bold;";
      if($this->state->italic) $span .= "font-style:italic;";
      if($this->state->underline) $span .= "text-decoration:underline;";
      if($this->state->end_underline) $span .= "text-decoration:none;";
      if($this->state->strike) $span .= "text-decoration:strikethrough;";
      if($this->state->hidden) $span .= "display:none;";
      if($this->state->fontsize != 0) $span .= "font-size: {$this->state->fontsize}px;";
      $this->output .= "<span style='{$span}'>";
    }

    protected function EndState()
    {
      $this->output .= "</span>";
    }

    protected function FormatControlSymbol($symbol)
    {
      if($symbol->symbol == '\'')
      {
        $this->BeginState();
        $this->output .= htmlentities(chr($symbol->parameter), ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1');
        $this->EndState();
      }
    }

    protected function FormatText($text)
    {
      $this->BeginState();
      $this->output .= $text->text;
      $this->EndState();
    }
  }
```

**Para usar:**

```
$reader = new RtfReader();
$rtf = file_get_contents("arquivo.rtf"); //Ou o campo que contem a mensagem
$reader->Parse($rtf)
```

**Chamada para a conversão:**

```
$formatter = new RtfHtml();
echo $formatter->Format($reader->root);
```

Para o Desktop você pode usar um componente `TWebBrowser` que ele fara a leitura e interpretação de todo HTML.

```
procedure CarregaMensagem; //Lendo o campo que contem a informação gravada em HTML/RTF
begin      
  if (Pos('{\rtf1\',Copy(CAMPO_QUE_CONTEM_A_INFORMAÇÃO, 1, 7)) > 0) then
    //Carrega com TRichEdit
  else
    //Carrega com TWebBrowser
end;
```

Caso não seja viável modificar as duas plataformas, você ainda pode gravar o HTML em RTF. Segue Pergunta e Resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605936/htmlcss-to-rtf-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

<s>A sua pergunta me faz entender que é sobre Delphi e html deve ser apenas o resultado final. Não dá pra entender bem e nem qual o objetivo, se Delphi é obrigátorio ou se pode ser uma aplicação em html mesmo, já que usou a tag [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap).</s>

Se o que você quer é portar o documento .rtf para plataformas web mas ainda quer poder usar com a sua aplicação Delphi então você pode usar o https://github.com/tbluemel/rtf.js que é javascript, veja um exemplo com Drag-and-Drop e FileReader API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.binarytransport.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.svg.css">
<script src="jquery.svg.min.js"></script>
<script src="../rtf.js"></script>
<script src="../wmf.js"></script>
<script>
function closeDoc(reset) {
    $("#havemeta").hide();
    $("#meta").empty();
    $("#content").empty();
    $("#dropzone").show();
    $("#closebutton").hide();
    $("#tools").hide();
    if (reset) {
        $("#samplecombo").val("");
    }
}
function beginLoading() {
    closeDoc(false);
    $("#dropzone").hide();
    $("#content").text("Loading...");
}
function setPictBorder(elem, show) {
    return elem.css("border", show ? "1px dotted red" : "none");
}
function setUnsafeLink(elem, warn) {
    return elem.css("border", warn ? "1px dashed red" : "none");
}
function displayRtfFile(blob) {
    try {
        var showPicBorder = $("#showpicborder").prop("checked");
        var warnHttpLinks = $("#warnhttplink").prop("checked");
        var settings = {
            onPicture: function(create) {
                var elem = create().attr("class", "rtfpict"); // WHY does addClass not work on <svg>?!
                return setPictBorder(elem, showPicBorder);
            },
            onHyperlink: function(create, hyperlink) {
                var url = hyperlink.url();
                var lnk = create();
                if (url.substr(0, 7) == "http://") {
                    // Wrap http:// links into a <span>
                    var span = setUnsafeLink($("<span>").addClass("unsafelink").append(lnk), warnHttpLinks);
                    span.click(function(evt) {
                        if ($("#warnhttplink").prop("checked")) {
                            evt.preventDefault();
                            alert("Unsafe link: " + url);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    return {
                        content: lnk,
                        element: span
                    };
                } else {
                    return {
                        content: lnk,
                        element: lnk
                    };
                }
            },
        };
        var doc = new RTFJS.Document(blob, settings);
        var haveMeta = false;
        var meta = doc.metadata();
        for (var prop in meta) {
            $("#meta").append($("<div>").append($("<span>").text(prop + ": ")).append($("<span>").text(meta[prop].toString())));
            haveMeta = true;
        }
        if (haveMeta)
            $("#havemeta").show();
        $("#content").empty().append(doc.render());
        $("#closebutton").show();
        $("#tools").show();
        console.log("All done!");
    } catch(e) {
        if (e instanceof RTFJS.Error)
            $("#content").text("Error: " + e.message);
        else
            throw e;
    }
}
function loadRtfFile(file) {
    beginLoading();
    $.ajax({
        url: file,
        dataType: "binary",
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(evt) {
                displayRtfFile(evt.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(result);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#content").text("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#closebutton").click(function() {
        closeDoc(true);
    });

    $("#dropzone")
        .on("drop", function(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation()
            evt.preventDefault();

            var files = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
            if (files.length > 1) {
                alert("Please only drop one file!");
            } else {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(evt) {
                    beginLoading();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        displayRtfFile(evt.target.result);
                    }, 100);
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
            }
        })
        .on("dragover", function(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation()
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
    closeDoc(true);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin: 4pt;">
    <span>
        <form>
            <input id="closebutton" type="button" value="Fechar" style="display: none;"/>
        </form>
    </span>
</div>
<div id="dropzone" style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 6pt; border: 2pt solid #dddddd; padding: 30pt;">
    Arraste e solte um arquivo RTF aqui
</div>
<div style="background-color:#f0ffff;display:none;" id="havemeta">
    <div>Metadata:</div>
    <div id="meta"></div>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Você pode usar no `#content` o parametro `contenteditable="true"` e assim poderá editar o documento via html, mas terá que converter novamente para .rtf, pois ele estará em .html até aqui.

Para entender o básico do uso dele é:

```
var doc = new RTFJS.Document(blob, settings);
document.getElementById("meu-editor").innerHTML = doc.render();
```

ou

```
var doc = new RTFJS.Document(blob, settings);
document.getElementById("meu-editor").value = doc.render();
```

Vai depender do tipo de editor que usa.

Comment: Seguinte, não vejo forma de ficar mais clara a minha pergunta, acredito que você esteja indo por um contexto errado, mas vamos lá, eu tenho uma aplicação web que possui um editor de texto, no caso ele utiliza bootstrap, não que o bootstrap seja algo relevante, eu preciso escrever textos em RTF e ler em HTML é isto, uma das dúvidas que você possa ter seria, por que salvar em RTF? por que existe outra aplicação (Delphi) que só consegue criar textos e exibi-los em RTF.

Comment: O @Júnior Moreira conseguiu entender bem a minha intenção e me indicou, já que não encontrou nenhum editor ou library que faça conversão de ida e volta em RTF que eu salve em HTML e acrescente um if no delphi para identificar se é html para em vez de mostrar um memo mostrar uma WebView e no web, se for RTF fazer converter para HTML para poder exibir.

Comment: @Highlander É justamente isto que estou falando, uma hora você fala de um editor de texto bootstrap (o que se supõe que é html+javascript) e outra hora você fala do editor do Delphi `TRichEdit`. Então fica realmente difícil de entender, acho que a minha resposta deve lhe ajudar, se o que eu entendi é que você já tem o .rtf gerado pela aplicação escrita em Delphi, então você quer converter pra html, estou certo? Então é isto justamente que o `new RTFJS.Document(blob, settings);` faz. agora se isto não resolve, devo presumir que a tag javascript não tem nada a ver com a pergunta....

Comment: ... Então a solução que procura é 100% em delphi. @Highlander

Comment: @Highlander de qualquer maneira eu editei a pergunta. Note que o código com drag-and-drop é apenas um exemplo pra ver como a biblioteca funciona. O que importa é você usar o `new RTFJS.Document(blob, settings);`. Mas se a solução não serve por ser em javascript, então recomendo que edite a pergunta e use as tags que são apenas relevantes ao problema. Pois se javascript não serve então é porque deve ser resolvido com alguma lib pra Delphi mesmo ou algum parse em objectpascal. Por favor não me leve a mal, são apenas dicas, sempre presuma boa intenção: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice ;)